# Get Infinispan JMX Statistics from Java

Tags: infinispan

I am new to Infinispan. I am trying to get statistics of cache by my Java code. By googling out, I found out some of the ways but nothing turned out to be a solution for me. Please have a look at the code and please let me know where I am missing.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.infinispan.Cache;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfiguration;
import org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager;

public class InfinispanCacheStats {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        GlobalConfiguration globalConfig = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder()
                  .globalJmxStatistics()
                  .enable()
                   .build();

        Configuration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .expiration().wakeUpInterval(5000l).lifespan(1000l).maxIdle(500l)
                   .build();
        config.jmxStatistics().enabled();

        DefaultCacheManager m = new DefaultCacheManager(globalConfig, config, true);
//      DefaultCacheManager m = new DefaultCacheManager("D:\\infinispan.xml");
        Cache<Integer, String> cache = m.getCache();
        cache.start();
        System.out.println(m.getCache().getAdvancedCache().getStats().getStores());
    }
}
```

I also tried configuring infinispan.xml file and providing it to DefaultCacheManager(), but it produces the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.infinispan.lifecycle.ModuleLifecycle: Provider org.infinispan.query.impl.LifecycleManager could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ServiceFinder.addServices(ServiceFinder.java:60)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ServiceFinder.load(ServiceFinder.java:42)
    at org.infinispan.util.ModuleProperties.resolveModuleLifecycles(ModuleProperties.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.<init>(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:94)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:292)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:271)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:244)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:231)
    at com.practice.asrl.infinispan.InfinispanCacheStats.main(InfinispanCacheStats.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Logger implementation class org.infinispan.query.logging.Log_$logger has no matching constructor
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2256)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
    at org.infinispan.util.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:21)
    at org.infinispan.query.impl.LifecycleManager.<clinit>(LifecycleManager.java:82)
    ... 16 more
```

Content of infinispan.xml :

```
<infinispan>
<cache-container statistics="true"/>
</infinispan>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the statistics from the ConfigurationBuilder object. They are disabled by default.

```
Configuration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.expiration().wakeUpInterval(5000l).lifespan(1000l).maxIdle(500l)
            .jmxStatistics().enable()
            .build();
```

When you call `config.jmxStatistics().enabled();` this will tell you if the statistics are enabled or not, but that won't change the configuration.